# Matplotlib Not Working Through PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I was under the impression that PyCharm now has the ability to support plotting using matplotlib. However, if I try to import matplotlib I get the following error, which appears when numpy tries to import multiarray.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I can plot fine through iPython. Is this an issue with PyCharm, and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1. It does support plotting using matplotlib, so the problem must be something to do with your system. 2. Have you checked that you've set up the correct interpreter settings for running your code?

Comment: Good point. They haven't been updated in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the project interpreter had been changed, and wasn't looking at my Anaconda distribution